# What is the definition of a set of "purely mathematical" objects?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, reference-request, set-theory

I was originally planning to post this on Math Stack Exchange, but I decided this was a better stack exchange. According to the axioms of set theory, there exists a set containing just an apple, and also a set containing an apple and a circle, as well as a set containing just a circle. However, only the last set would be studied in mathematics. The other two sets would not contain purely mathematical objects. But, what is the definition of a set that contains only mathematical objects? Is there a rigorous notion of such a thing? Also, is this discussed somewhere in some philosophy or math text? I would like some references.

Comment: According to the axioms... NO, there are no apples in mathematics.

Comment: Reference: every textbook about axiomatic set theory.

Comment: Perhaps even eating a set containing aleph0 number of apples won’t help you penetrate the pure form of material set theory such as ZFC or NFU which could have urelements, OTOH even after reading every set book there are won’t have the same effect as one real apple… Maybe another interesting question?…

Comment: Under the standard set theory (ZFC), speaking rigorously, *all* "purely mathematical objects" are sets and nothing else is. Other objects that we think of as something else, numbers, circles, functions, are nothing more than informal aliases for certain types of sets. So only those objects that can be built from the empty set, whose existence is postulated, by means prescribed in the axioms qualify as "purely mathematical", see [Von Neumann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe).

Comment: @Conifold Ah, but can't you have a set containing non-mathematical objects, like the set of humans alive now? My question is not about ZFC per se, but about sets in general. Perhaps my question would be answered if we have a precise definition of what a mathematical object is, and then we can define a purely mathematical set as a set that contains only mathematical objects.

Comment: The title names sets of "purely mathematical objects", not "sets in general". If you are looking for a mathematical definition of sets with non-mathematical objects that would not be forthcoming, theories cannot import external content they do not circumscribe *and* stay rigorous. On the other hand, one precise definition of mathematical object is - a set of ZFC.

Comment: With a "philosophical flavor": M. Potter, [Set Theory and its Philosophy (2004)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%E2%80%93Potter_set_theory)